# Equivalent definitions of maximal direct summand in a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, modules

I would like to show that the following statements are equivalent:

> Let $M$ be a right $R$-module, and $N$ a submodule of $M$, $N \neq M$.
>
> $N$ is a direct summand of $M$, such that $N \oplus K$ for some $K$ indecomposable module *iff* $N$ is maximal in the set of those submodules of $M$, that are not equal to $M$, and that are direct summands in $M$.

**Proof:**

The left implication is simple - if we pick any complement $K$ to $N$, $K$ has to be indecomposable, if it weren't, we would get a contradiction with maximality of $N$.

The right implication - let $L$ be a direct summand of $M$, such that $N \subseteq L \neq M$, $K$ be some indecomposable complement of $N$, and $J$ some complement of $L$. Using modularity, we can see that $L = (N\oplus K ) \cap L = N \oplus (K \cap L) $. Therefore, $M = N \oplus K = N \oplus (K\cap L) \oplus J$. From the isomorphism theorems and the fact that $N$ is indecomposable, it follows that $K \cap L$ has to be $0$ - and so $L=N$, and so $N$ is maximal in submodules of $M$ that are not equal to $M$, and that are direct summands, as we wanted to show.